# check every values in array of object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object like this :

```
const object = [
     {name: 'John', age: 15},
     {name: 'Victor', age: 15},
     {name: 'Emile', age: 14}
     ]
```

I need to check if in this array all age are 15. ( just need a boolean for answer )
I need to use something like 'every' method but how with an object ?

Comment: `every()` works with an array. The callback function can check the property of the object.

Comment: `obj.age == 15`

Comment: I asume you mean *are 15 **or older***?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `every`:

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value. [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

So the code will be like:

```js
const object = [
    {name: 'John', age: 15},
    {name: 'Victor', age: 15},
    {name: 'Emile', age: 14}
]
     
const isValid = object.every(item => item.age === 15)
console.log({isValid})
```

This is `js` functional ability to test all your elements states.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to extract the property you want to compare

```js
const object = [ {name: 'John', age: 15},{name: 'Victor', age: 15},{name: 'Emile', age: 14}]

let op = object.every(({ age }) => age === 15)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the length of the array with length of array of objects with required age.

```js
const object = [ 
    {name: 'John', age: 15},
    {name: 'Victor', age: 15},
    {name: 'Emile', age: 14}
];
function hasAge(pAge, object) {
    return object.length === object.filter(({ age }) => age === pAge).length;
}
console.log(hasAge(15, object));
```