# replace for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm a bit of a JS noob and I'm currently trying to learn array functions.

When trying to refactor some of my old code I stumbled across this:

```
export const determineValue = (events) => {
  let eligible = false
  for (const event of events) {
    if (event.eventType === "1") {
      eligible = true
    } else if (event.eventType === "2") {
      eligible = false
      return eligible
    }
  }

  return eligible
}
```

For this case, `"1"` and `"2"` are the only possible values of `event.eventType`.

How can I write this compactly?

Are there any best practices to consider here?

Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Comment: Do different `eventType`'s exist besides `"1"` and `"2"`?

Comment: For this case, no :)

Comment: In that case you are basically checking if every element in your array has a property `eventType` with value `"1"`. So `return events.every(event => event.eventType === "1")`. Alternatively you can check if there is any property with value `"2"` and invert the outcome `!events.some(event => event.eventType === "2")`.(There is probably a good duplicate for this somewhere.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check every values in array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486834/check-every-values-in-array-of-object)

Comment: I see that it isn't entirely identical because you also return `false` when the array is empty. You can still use `.every()` or `.some()`, but you'll need an extra step: `events.length === 0 ? false : events.every(event => event.eventType === "1")`. (Though just a regular if-statement instead of a conditional operator might be better readable.)

Answer (score 2):

A simplified solution would be

```
//example setup
const events = [{"eventType":"1"},{"eventType":"2"}];

// Solution 
const eventTypes = events.map(x => x.eventType);
return eventTypes.includes("1") && !eventTypes.includes("2");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like this :

```
const determineValue = (events) => {
  return events.length > 0 && !(events.every(input => input.eventType === "2"));
}
```

If `events.length > 0` is false, the part behind the `&&` is not executed, and the function immediately returns `false`.

Otherwise it checks if every item in `events` has a value `"2"` for its property `eventType`. It returns `false` if the check succeeds and `true` if it fails, due to the `!` in front of it.

#### Demo

```js
const events0 =[];
const events1 =[{eventType: "1"}, {eventType: "2"}, {eventType: "1"}];
const events2 =[{eventType: "2"}, {eventType: "2"}, {eventType: "2"}];

const determineValue = (events) => {
  return events.length > 0 && !(events.every(input => input.eventType === "2"));
}

console.log(determineValue(events0));
console.log(determineValue(events1));
console.log(determineValue(events2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the eligble events are type 1 - all you need to do is filter the events array for those and then return the length of the filtered array.

```js
const events =[{eventType: 1},{eventType: 1},{eventType: 2},{eventType: 2},{eventType: 1},{eventType: 1}];

const determineValue = (events) => {
  return events.filter(x => x.eventType === 1).length
}

;
console.log(determineValue(events)); // gives 4 events are type 1
console.log(events.length); // gives 6 events in total
```

To enhance it and you can also pass in the type that you want to count (in case you want to count the ineligible events instead)

```js
const events =[{eventType: 1},{eventType: 1},{eventType: 2},{eventType: 2},{eventType: 1},{eventType: 1}];

const determineValue = (events, value) => {
  return events.filter(x => x.eventType === value).length
}

;
console.log(determineValue(events, 1)); // gives 4 events are type 1
console.log(determineValue(events, 2)); //gives 2 events are type 2
console.log(events.length); // gives 6 events in total
```